# What is difference between "?" and "!" in Swift?

Tags: swift

I know what "?" and "!" mean when I declare variables in Swift. But what do they mean when *using* these variables? For example, in this code:

```
var attachment: NSTextAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder.png")
attachment.image!.size ... // or attachment.image?.size ...
```

What's the difference between `attachment.image!.size` and `attachment.image?.size`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use `attachment.image!.size` if you're guaranteed that `image?` isn't `nil`. If you're wrong (and it is `nil`) your app will crash. This is called *forced unwrapping*.

If you're *not sure* it won't be `nil`, use `image?`.

In your case `image!` is OK, since you control whether `placeholder.png` exists.

Read all of the documentation on [Swift Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_485). It's a basic and fundamental part of the language.

Answer (score 35):

**what is ! and ?:**

- Use ? if the value can become nil in the future, so that you test for
  this.
- Use ! if it really shouldn't become nil in the future,
  but it needs to be nil initially.

if You are using `attachment.image!.size` any variable with ! means, compiler don't bother about that variable has any value or `nil`.
it goes to take action further, it will here try to get size of image. if `attachment.image` is `nil` then app will be crash here.

While, `attachment.image?.size`, this will make sure you, if `attachment.image` isn't nil then further action will be take place, otherwise But it confirm Application will not be crash in case of `nil` value of `image` .

**Summary:**

We should have to use !, when we make sure option type variable has value at a time and we need to take action on it further, Otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `!` and the variable is `nil` it will trigger run time error but if use `?` it will fail gracefully.
More detail information in [apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245)

Answer (score -1):

Both symbols ! and ? used for optionals. We should have to use !, when we make sure option type variable has value at a time and we need to take action on it.Otherwise It will crash if variable value is nil.And if you are using ?, Application will not crash in nil case.

You can follow this link for more information:- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twBfiKsbHP8