# Swift variable used before initialised

Tags: swift

If I write a code like this in swift it says variable x used before initialized. This seems legit in java. Why is this not possible in swift and how do I achieve the same?

```
  var x:Int
  var y:Int  = 0

  if (y==0) {
      x=0
   }

   if (y==1) {
      x=1
   }

   y=x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `!` or `?` to define variable without initializing

```
    var x:Int?
    var y:Int  = 0

    if (y==0) {
        x=0
    }

    if (y==1) {
        x=1
    }

    y=x!
```

OR

```
    var x:Int!
    var y:Int  = 0

    if (y==0) {
        x=0
    }

    if (y==1) {
        x=1
    }

    y=x
```

Comment: whats the difference between your two examples?

Comment: @BlazeyJohn Refer this for difference between `?` and `!`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895098/what-is-difference-between-and-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

A non-optional variable cannot be used before being initialized.
But it's possible to even use `let` when the variable is guaranteed to be initialized before using it

```
  let x: Int
  var y : Int = 0

  if (y==0) {
      x=0
   } else if (y==1) {
      x=1
   } else {
      x=2
   }

   y=x
```

Comment: Since Swift 1.2 this expression is valid: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22

Answer (score 0):

To use variables, it is an issue that you have to init them or you can force the variable with `!` to unwrap or you can init it with optional by using `?`. In this case you can use it like that

```
  var x:Int!  /// var x:Int?
  var y:Int  = 0

   if (y == 0) {
      x=0
   }

   if (y == 1) {
      x=1
   }
```