# Get credential for updating email with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to update user's email. Google Firebase's docs say that I need to get the credential, when I try `var credential: FIRAuthCredential` and using it in the closure `user?.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential)` the error says that `Variable 'credential' used before being initialized` I need to initialized this, how could I do this? do i have to pop up the action sheet to ask the user the password again?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: read that, bro, still can't work. thanks

Comment: This one should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207426/swift-variable-used-before-initialised And read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330 and of course https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309