# iOS Swift 3 - Argument labels '(of:)' do not match any available overloads Error

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm getting the error message `Argument labels '(of:)' do not match any available overloads`. Below is the code I'm using.

```
let prefs = UserDefaults.standard
var id: String!
if var array = prefs.string(forKey: "myArray"){
    if let index = array.index(of: id) {
        array.remove(at: index)
        prefs.setValue(array, forKey: "myArray")
    }
}
```

I've seen a lot of answers on Stack Overflow with very similar code to that. So I'm not quite sure why this wouldn't be working.

Basically I'm just trying to remove the element in the array that = `id` then set that new array to the user defaults.

**Update**

Just updated the code above to show how `array` is getting defined. `id` is a string that is defined in a separate section.

Comment: Are you sure that your id is int?

Comment: The important information is missing: How are `array` and `id` defined?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. It works perfectly in playground with an array of strings. Please share the array's initialization and the same goes for the id

Comment: Just updated the question. `id` is defined in a separate class when the object is created pretty much.

Comment: @ridvankucuk No, `id` is a string not an int

Comment: Your  `array`  variable is a `String` ....

Comment: String has no member `index(of:)`, an array of string does

Comment: You can get the array with prefs.array keyword

Comment: `prefs.array(forKey: "selectedTags")` ok now using that. Still getting errors on the `let index` line. `Cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(of: String!)'`

Comment: Lookup the documentation (or use the Quick Help inspector): What type does `prefs.array(forKey:)` return? What type do you want it to have?

Comment: It returns `The array associated with the specified key`. Which makes sense. I should be able to get the index of an element in that array.

Comment: check the answer. You cannot, because `prefs.array(forKey: "selectedTags")`  returns `[Any]` and you try to search for an index of type `String`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By accessing `prefs.string(forKey: "myArray")`, you are getting a `String`, not an array of strings. You should use this:

```
if var prefs.array(forKey: "myArray") as? [String] { }
```

**or**

```
if var prefs.value(forKey: "myArray") as? [String] { }
```

Make sure to not forget putting `as! [String]`, because the first method returns `[Any]`, an which can contain objects of any type, not specifically `String`. Then your error should be solved, because `index(of: )` can only be used on Arrays of specified types.

Hope it helps!

Comment: `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String]'` Getting that error

Comment: wait a second, trying to reproduce that

Comment: on what line exactly??

Comment: `if var array = prefs.value(forKey: "myArray") as! [String] {` or `if var array = prefs.array(forKey: "myArray") as! [String] {`

Comment: Regarding the conditional binding error replace `!` with `?`

Comment: @vadian oh, sorry, my bad

Comment: After making all those adjustments it seems to build without any errors. Thanks so much!!! I guess I got to do some research on all of that. The whole `!` `?` stuff is very confusing to me for some reason. It seems kinda simple on the surface but for some reason I'm still struggling with it.

Comment: If you have got any other questions on this, make sure to ask. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895098/what-is-difference-between-and-in-swift) on StackOverflow should be helpful. And maybe [Apple's Documentation on Nil-Coalescing Operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID60) would help you understand them even better

Answer (score 0):

Just make an  <kbd>alt</kbd>  + **Click** on an "array" variable to make sure it is of type Array (`[String]`), not a `String`. To apply `.index(of:)` method it must be an array.

Like this: [image: checking the type]

String does not have a method `.index(of:)`. That's what the  error is pointing at. And sure make a cast to `[String]?` if it fits.